# Connect to MongoDB Atlas cluster from an Azure App Service

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a web app on Azure that connect to a MongoDB cluster hosted on Atlas (cloud.mongodb.com).

I'd like to use Atlas so I don't have to care about MongoDb configurations.
The issue is that I get a timeout connecting my cluster. I have to set the app service ip in my mongo cluster whitelist, but If I try to download the page http://www.whatsmyip.org/ I get every time a different IP.

On the azure panel I've tried everything, set a VNET integration, set an ASE, a gateway. I really don't know how to expose the public IP.

However I have a VM that can query the mongo cluster, it has a Network interface with a public ip and a nsg (firewall).

Comment: This question is really about discovery of outbound IP address for App Service web apps, not mongodb. And there are questions (and answers) about this very topic. TL;DR there's no single outbound IP address for web apps.

Comment: You are right, I've explained the whole problem to eventually find an alternative solution. How should I have to host the app? Does it make sense to use Atlas if I deploy all my other enterprise services on azure?

Comment: I couldn't find the panel with the outbound ips. settings -> properties -> OUTBOUND IP ADDRESSES I have set them in the whitelist and it works

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Whitelisting the outbound connections should be an explicit instruction in the Azure / MongoDB documentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 22):

To expand Paolo's answer as it wasn't too clear and I had to do some extra research.

In the Azure portal, select your App Service and scroll down to the Settings section in the menu (headed by overview) and select properties.

Scroll down until you find the Outbound IP Addresses. These are the ones you will want to add to your whitelist in Atlas.

Useful Links:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/waws/2017/02/01/how-do-i-determine-the-outbound-ip-addresses-of-my-azure-app-service/

Comment: Hi, this solution was surely correct in 1918, but now it seems the Outbound IP address configuration is not there anymore, not with an API. Any Idea how we can do it now?

Comment: @Rachel - In `App Settings` > `Properties` I can see the section `Outbound IP addresses`, I get the same values when following the `Azure CLI` snippet here:    https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#find-outbound-ips

Answer (score 1):

You can whitelist 0.0.0.0/0 and then rely on user authentication.  Alternatively, you can use AWS as an alternative to Azure and use VPC peering.

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-vpc-peering-for-mongodb-atlas