# Configure network access to MongoDB cluster from Azure App Service

Tags: mongodb, azure

I'm trying to configure network access of a MongoDB cluster to allow connections from an Azure App Service. I found the outbound IP addresses of my App Service in the Azure portal (see [Azure docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#find-outbound-ips)). And entered them in the IP access list according to [MongoDB Atlas docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/security/ip-access-list/#add-ip-access-list-entries). I appended "/32" to the IP addresses to allow only a single host ([CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)).

However, when trying to connect on App Service start I get an error indicating to check the IP whitelist of the MongoDB cluster.

This actually seems to be the problem, because adding 0.0.0.0/0 (allow access from anywhere) solves the problem.

What could be the problem here?

I double checked the outbound IP addresses of the Azure App Service and the IP access list from the MongoDB Cluster.

What I did was indeed the answer to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50756165/999309), so I think I'm missing something...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I only added the IP addresses listed in the "outbound IP addresses" property of my Azure App Service. After adding the IP addresses listed in the "Additional Outbound IP Addresses" property also the App Service connects to the MongoDB cluster successfully.

This is somewhat surprising to me because the [documentation on when outbound IPs change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#when-outbound-ips-change) says that the "...set of outbound IP addresses for your app changes when you perform one of the following actions:

- Delete an app and recreate it in a different resource group (deployment unit may change).
- Delete the last app in a resource group and region combination and recreate it (deployment unit may change).
- Scale your app between the lower tiers (Basic, Standard, and Premium), the PremiumV2, and the PremiumV3 tier (IP addresses may be added to or subtracted from the set).

..."

None of the above actions happened.

Answer (score 2):

Actually /32 is not a valid CIDR in Azure. The minimum size of a single VNET is /29.
This will restrict your range to only 3 IPs (not 8 as you would expect), as Azure will reserve the first four IPs and the last one for internal routing.

Please consider also that if you are running the MongoDB cluster inside a private network and it is not exposed externally via a network appliance (such as Application Gateway, Load Balancer, Front Door or Traffic Manager), you will need to enable VNET Integration on Azure Web App side.

If this is your case, navigate through your App in the portal and go into the "Networking" blade.
Here you can add VNET Integration, but you should consider that in this case the minimum size of your subnet can only be /28 (you cannot add a smaller subnet)

Comment: I'm hosting the MongoDB cluster using MongoDB Atlas on Azure. Maybe I need to look into the Azure settings of this deployment? Do I even have control of it?

Comment: I don't think that Azure settings are the right place to look. Re-reading your question, seems that you added only one IP for your WebApp in the Atlas IP list, did you try also to add all the set of outbound public IP that a Web App should have?
In general if you are not using a NAT IP or if yor WebApp is not part of an ASE, you should find about 25 outbound IPs in the networking blade

Comment: I added about 8 different IP addresses. There is another property "additionally possible IP addresses". The docs suggest that those are only used when the app service is moved to another subscription, resource group or tier. But I'll try to add those next.

Comment: I added the IP addresses from the "additionally possible IP addresses" and now it works 