# MongoDB Atlas blocking requests from Azure web app even after adding web app outbound IP addresses to MongoDB Atlas > Network Access

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-app-service, mongodb-atlas

**Steps to reproduce**

**01)**  `portal.azure.com` > `[ select my web app service ]` > `Properties` > `Outbound IP addresses` > `[ copy ]`

**02)**  `MongoDB Atlas` > `Network Access` > `+ Add IP Address`

(for each outgoing IP address of the web app and my own PC IP address for local testing)

**Expected Behaviour**

I can make requests to MongoDB Atlas.

**Actual Behaviour**

It works:

- In local environment
- In non-local environment (i.e calling from Azure web app) if I 'allow access from anywhere' in `MongoDB Atlas` > `Network Access`

It does not work:

- In non-local environment (i.e calling from Azure web app) if I remove the 'allow access from anywhere' in `MongoDB Atlas` > `Network Access`

It times out with this message in Azure web app log stream and then crashes the app:

```
/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:543
drainWaitQueue(topology[kWaitQueue], new error_1.MongoTopologyClosedError());
MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed
at processWaitQueue (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:543:46)
at Topology.selectServer (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:290:9)
at Topology.<anonymous> (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:43:94)
at node:internal/util:364:7
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at Topology.selectServerAsync (node:internal/util:350:12)
at executeOperationAsync (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:39:24)
at /home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:12:45
at maybeCallback (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:338:21)
at executeOperation (/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:12:38) {
[Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

I am testing the web app service and therefore cannot get Microsoft Support without paying for a support subscription.

I am very sure that I added all the IP addresses correctly.

*Related Reading*

[How can I determine the IP address of an Azure hosted WebApp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40488443/how-can-i-determine-the-ip-address-of-an-azure-hosted-webapp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this worked:

**01)**  `portal.azure.com` > `[ select my web app service ]` > `Properties` > `Outbound IP addresses` > `[ copy ]`  (this has 7 IP addresses)

**02)**  `portal.azure.com` > `[ select my web app service ]` > `Properties` > `Additional Outbound IP Addresses` > `[ copy ]` (this has 25 IP addresses, including 6 of the ones above)

**03)**  `MongoDB Atlas` > `Network Access` > `+ Add IP Address`

(for each of these outgoing IP addresses of the web app and my own PC IP address for local testing)

The reason I didn't initially add these 'additional' ip addresses is that the help text next to the `Additional Outbound IP Addresses` section in Azure states:

> Additional Outbound IP Addresses represents the union of all possible outbound addresses that can be used when running in either Premium V2 or other SKUs.

I am using free tier, so not sure why those additional IP's were being utilised.

Another person seems to have experienced the same behaviour here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72436266